How do I show that if $a^2, b^2\in F$, then $ab\in F$?
Consider a field extension $L/F$ with $\text{char}(F)\neq 2$, Now $a,b $$\in L$,$a,b \neq0$,and  $a^{2},b^{2} \in F$.
The Problem:
If we have field extension $F(a)=F(b)$, how to prove $ab\in F$?
My Idea:
I don't have a good idea, I just know $(ab)^{2} \in F$ ,but what to do next? maybe by contraction?

What's the point of saying that your idea is that you don't have a good idea?

Maybe I am just showing my ignorance here, but I don't know what "suppose that $a,b\not\in F$, but $a^2,b^2\in F$" means. If $a$ and $b$ are not in the field, then what do $a^2$ and $b^2$ even mean? Are you assuming that $a$ and $b$ live in some (understated) extension field of $F$?

I change my description，maybe you can understand  it better？

Both extensions are quadratic, so we have $$a=c_1+bc_2$$ It follows that $(a-bc_2)^2\in F$, in particular $ab\in F$.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
